# Arena Allocator Allocation Method & Violation Writing Issue

Tags: visual-c++

Basically I'm trying to create an Arena Allocator without using structs, classes, or the new operator to manually manage memory. I have a defined size, a character pool, an allocation method and a freeMemory display method.

Note that `pool[0]` is my index which will keep track of where the memory has last been filled.

```
const int size = 50000;
char pool[size];

void start() {
    pool[0] = 1;
}

int freeMemory(void) {
    int freemem = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(pool[i] == NULL) {
            freemem++;
        }
    } 
    return freemem;
}

 void* allocate(int aSize)
 {

if(freeMemory() == 0)
  {
        out();
  }

else
{
    char* p = NULL;
    int pos = pool[0];
    pool[pos] = (char) a;
    p = &pool[pos];
    pool[0] += a;
    return((void*) &pool[pos]);
}
}
```

In the main.cpp:

```
start();
long* test1 = (long *) allocate(sizeof(long));
cout << freeMemory() << endl; //Returns 49999
*test1 = 0x8BADF00D; //Breaks here
cout << freeMemory() << endl;
```

It breaks when I try to use 0x8BADF00D and I believe I'm having issues initializing some of these variables too.

Unhandled exception at 0x000515f7 in MemoryManagerC.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000004 on 0x8BADF00D

Comment: I can't see how you got `*test1 = 0xTESTMEEE` to compile.  Is that really your code?

Comment: Yep. I mean the TESTMEEE is just a placeholder. I've tried other things like 0x8BADF00D and FOO, ect.

Comment: `pool[0]` is a char and will overflow after a small number of bytes allocated. Why don't you just declare a `size_t` to hold the `pos` as a field? And what is `a`?

Answer (score 1):

The code below has numerous bugs.

```
char* pointer;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    *pointer = pool[i];
    if(pointer != NULL)
    {
        pointer = (char*) a;
        return((void*) i); //return the pointer
    }
 }
```

This line copies a character to an unknown memory location.  Since `pointer` has never been initialized, we can only guess where it's pointing

```
    *pointer = pool[i];
```

You probably meant to copy a pointer.

```
    pointer = &pool[i];
```

Although if you *did* mean to copy a pointer from the `pool` array, this will **always** be true.  None of the elements in that array reside at address `NULL`.

```
    if(pointer != NULL)
```

Now this code changes `pointer` to point to...more invalid addresses.  When `a` is `sizeof(long)`, that size is reinterpreted to be a memory address.  Memory address `0x00000004` most likely.

```
        pointer = (char*) a;
```

And then this will return the address `0x00000000`, in your case.  Because `i` is `0`.

```
        return((void*) i); //return the pointer
```

Comment: You are correct in that I mixed up the *pointer = pool[i] when I meant to say pointer = &pool[i]; The if check was left over by mistake from an edit I had been making. Silly enough I forgot to remove it. However, after fixing up the code a bit to include an index and not even bother with the pointer complication I previously had, I still get write errors on 0x00004. I've updated the OP to show the new changes I made.

Comment: @user2229804 I'm afraid this isn't your real code either.  `MM_pool` is undefined.  I recommend that you copy + paste an exact, complete program as a question.  People are going to have a really hard time helping you fix your program if what you're showing isn't really the program you're having trouble with.

Comment: Copy mistake. I tried to rewrite the code from scratch and named it something more constructive, but it didn't help as I got the same issue.
This is the program, I haven't made a deallocation method yet.

Comment: @user2229804 The code posted now does not compile.  I'm very sorry, but I've run out of ways to tell you that **this is not your real code**.  I can not fix your top-secret, invisible code.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with allocate:

```
char* pointer = NULL;
int pos = pool[0];
```

`pool[0]` is a `char`. It's not big enough to store indexes to all members of the array.

```
pool[pos] = (char) a;
```

I'm not sure what you're storing here, or why. You seem to be storing the size of the allocation *in* the space that you're allocating.

```
pointer = &pool[pos + a];
```

I think you're constructing a pointer to the memory *after* the allocated portion. Is that right?

```
pool[0] += a;
```

And here you're incrementing the offset that shows how much of the pool is allocated, except that a single `char` isn't going to be big enough for more than a tiny quantity of allocations.

```
return((void*) &pointer);
```

And now you're returning the *address* of the pointer variable. That's going to be an address on the stack, and unsafe to use. Even if you just the *contents* of `pointer` instead of its address, I think it would point after the region you just allocated in your pool.

There are also problems with freeMemory. It compares the contents of the pool (`char` elements) with NULL. This suggests you think it contains pointers, but they are just `char`s. It's not clear why unallocated parts of the pool would be 0. Do you even allow deallocation within the pool?

Perhaps you could explain how you intend the allocator to work? There's obviously a gap between what you think it should do and what it actually does, but it's not clear what you think it should do, so it's hard to give advice. How do you apportion space in the array? Do you allow deallocation? What information is supposed to be encoded where?

---

I just realised that allocate uses the undefined variable `a`. Is that supposed to be the same thing as the parameter `aSize`? That's what I assume here.

Comment: Deallocation will be supported, I just wanted to get allocation out of the way first.
The pointer being made I'm trying to make be the point after the allocation of the memory pool. So if I allocate for 0x8BADF00D, it will return the pointer in which the pool is free next.

As for the pool[0] - what would you suggest to hold my index that isn't a global variable? My goal is to try to keep everything inside pool array without additional variables. Why can't [0] hold the location? A char should be large enough no? The information in the array should just be the 0x8BADF00D.

Comment: I do plan on putting a string in it too for the string_pointer, but I've only gotten up until int_pointer before getting that error.

Comment: A `char` is only going to hold 8-bits on the vast majority of platforms, so the highest value it could hold is 255, assuming it's unsigned. If you must store the count in the array, you could reserve sizeof(int) slots for it, then use memcpy to copy bytes between the start of the array and an int variable. Why don't you want additional variables?

Answer (score 0):

a possible problem with your code might be here.

```
char* pointer;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    *pointer = pool[i];
```

The thing here is this might work on some compilers (it shouldn't in my opinion).

`pointer` here is not pointing to anything allocated. So when you do

```
*pointer = pool[i];
```

Where should pool[i] be copied to? 
For example let's say we delclared pointer like this.

```
char* pointer = NULL;
```

now it is clear that

```
*pointer = pool[i];
```

is wrong. 
`g++` (I have noticed) initializes pointers to NULL. So your code will segfault. VC++ might work because it didn't NULL initialize `pointer`. But you are writing to a memory location that's not yours.

Comment: You are right, I certainly had an initialization issue. But even after removing that or trying to fix it, it still is giving me a write error.

Comment: "g++ (I have noticed) initializes pointers to NULL" that is not true in general. This is a coincidence.